# C - determine if a number is prime

Tags: c#, c, primes

I am trying to come up with a method that takes an integer and returns a boolean to say if the number is prime or not and I don't know much C; would anyone care to give me some pointers?

Basically, I would do this in C# like this:

```
static bool IsPrime(int number)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0 && i != number)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Here's some pointers: int *ptr; int *ptr2; int *ptr3. Sorry couldn't help it.
How big are the numbers you will be checking? And also, do you want a heuristic or something that always works?

Comment: What's the point of 'i != number' when you have 'i < number' as a condition to execute the loop?

Comment: Take a look at this link this contains an explanation of how things work. http://cprogramming.language-tutorial.com/2012/01/check-whether-given-no-is-prime-or-not.html

Comment: Also note that checking `i < number` is overkill. By definition, if a number `x = a * b`, either `a` or `b` is `< int(sqrt(x))` and the other is greater. So your loop should only need to go up to `int(sqrt(x))`.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

OK, so forget about C.  Suppose I give you a number and ask you to determine if it's prime.  How do you do it?  Write down the steps clearly, *then* worry about translating them into code.

Once you have the algorithm determined, it will be much easier for you to figure out how to write a program, and for others to help you with it.

**edit:** Here's the C# code you posted:

```
static bool IsPrime(int number) {
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0 && i != number) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is *very nearly* valid C as is; there's no `bool` type in C, and no `true` or `false`, so you need to modify it a little bit (edit: Kristopher Johnson correctly points out that C99 added the stdbool.h header).  Since some people don't have access to a C99 environment (but you should use one!), let's make that very minor change:

```
int IsPrime(int number) {
    int i;
    for (i=2; i<number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0 && i != number) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This is a perfectly valid C program that does what you want.  We can improve it a little bit without too much effort.  First, note that `i` is always less than `number`, so the check that `i != number` always succeeds; we can get rid of it.

Also, you don't actually need to try divisors all the way up to `number - 1`; you can stop checking when you reach sqrt(number).  Since `sqrt` is a floating-point operation and that brings a whole pile of subtleties, we won't actually compute `sqrt(number)`.  Instead, we can just check that `i*i <= number`:

```
int IsPrime(int number) {
    int i;
    for (i=2; i*i<=number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

One last thing, though; there was a small bug in your original algorithm!  If `number` is negative, or zero, or one, this function will claim that the number is prime.  You likely want to handle that properly, and you may want to make `number` be unsigned, since you're more likely to care about positive values only:

```
int IsPrime(unsigned int number) {
    if (number <= 1) return 0; // zero and one are not prime
    unsigned int i;
    for (i=2; i*i<=number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This definitely isn't the fastest way to check if a number is prime, but it works, and it's pretty straightforward.  We barely had to modify your code at all!

Comment: FYI, the C99 standard defines a <stdbool.h> header that provides `bool`, `true`, and `false`.

Comment: also forgot to mention that i don't need to worry about 0, 1, or negatives, this is just running through a list of 50 numbers if i remember correctly but thank you again

Comment: @Kristopher: thanks, forgot about that one.  @Jimmy: happy to help, glad that it was only a documentation bug =)

Comment: You also can improve this (by nearly 50%) by only checking the odd numbers (treat 0,1,2 as special cases) and start at 3 in advance by 2 each time.

Comment: I know that it is simpler to compute a square than a square root, however computing a square on each iteration ought to cost MORE that computing the square root once and be done with it :x

Comment: On a modern out-of-order machine, the latency of the mul instruction to square i should be entirely hidden in the latency of the modulus, so there would be no appreciable performance win. On a strictly in-order machine, there is a win to be had using a hoisted square root, but that potentially raises issues of floating-point imprecision if the code were compiled on a platform with a large int type (64 bits or bigger). All that can be dealt with, but I thought it best to keep things simple and trivially portable. After all, if you care about speed, you're not using this algorithm at all.

Comment: @Tom you can improve a lot more by stopping at the floor(sqrt(number)).
Take 11, for example, floor(sqrt(11)) = 3. The number after 3 is 4, 3*4 = 12 > 11.

If you're using a naive sieve to check for primality, you only need to check odd numbers up to the sqrt of the original, aside from 2.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Agreed. I wrote a ruby script to test this:
331:
  Stephen: 0.000635
  Matthieu: 0.000611
68720001023:
  Stephen: 1.958449
  Matthieu: 0.003167
999999000001:
  Stephen: 7.293912
  Matthieu: 0.005871

Comment: @Calyth adding floor() to the function doesn't do anything different then sqrt() by itself does but it takes longer to complete the task.

Comment: @StephenCanon: The for loop terminating condition is: "i < number" then how come, if (number % i == 0 && i != number) holds? I am referring to "i != number"

Comment: -1. The final function gives the incorrect answer for [4294967291](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+4294967291+prime).

Comment: @StephenCanon: and you can also replace that post increment `i++` with `++i`. as it will also decrease one step of working.

Comment: @StephenCanon, I would use `i<number/i` to avoid overflow.  [Even better is to save the quotient and the remainder e.g. `for(i=2, q=number/i, r=number%i; i<q; i++, q=number/i, r=number%i`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556599/conditional-tests-in-primality-by-trial-division).

Comment: @Zboson: If we really want to nitpick, `number/i` is strictly worse than (pre-computed) `sqrt(number)`.  `number/i` performs one additional unnecessary division.  It also makes the loop condition depend on a long-latency operation; on an architecture with a pipelined divide, this could easily cause stalls due to limits on the number of unresolved branch predictions in flight at once.

Comment: @StephenCanon, you already do `number%i` so you get `number/i` for free. It's just as fast as `sqrt(number)`. Did you read my [conditional-tests-in-primality-by-trial-division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556599/conditional-tests-in-primality-by-trial-division)?

Comment: @Zboson: it's as fast *on an architecture without pipelined divide*, and it's no clearer (in my opinion, tastes may vary).

Comment: The code posted by the OP was already 100% valid C. So a large portion of this answer is just nonsense, there is no need to convert a single thing. `bool` `true` and `false` do exist in C. `static` functions exist in C and variable declarations inside for loops are allowed.

Comment: u can also get rid of all the even numbers, so i+=2

Comment: @Kasparov92 `i` starts from 2, so `i+=2` is not right. You can try to input 31 or 33 to test it.

Comment: @CyberMew let i start from 3 and i+=2 so that we move on all odd only

Comment: Being a highly voted answer, the corner errors deserve attention - _in code_.  1) `IsPrime(0 or 1)`  incorrectly reports true. 2) Undefined behavior with `IsPrime(int number)` and large `number`, 3) `IsPrime(unsigned number)`: `i*i<=number` is a problem when number near `UINT_MAX` as `i*i` overflows. Border line infinite loop when `number == UINT_MAX`.

Comment: The second function returns `1` for `n = 1` and 1 is not a prime number.

Answer (score 29):

I'm suprised that no one mentioned this.

Use the [Sieve Of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Details:

1. Basically nonprime numbers are divisible by another number besides 1 and themselves
2. Therefore: a nonprime number will be a product of prime numbers.

The sieve of Eratosthenes finds a prime number and stores it. When a new number is checked for primeness all of the previous primes are checked against the know prime list.

Reasons:

1. This algorithm/problem is known as "[Embarrassingly Parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel)"
2. It creates a collection of prime numbers
3. Its an example of a dynamic programming problem
4. Its quick!

Comment: It's also `O(n)` in space, and as long as your computation is for a single value, this is a huge waste of space for no performance gain.

Comment: (Actually `O(n log n)` or larger if you're supporting large numbers...)

Comment: Who computes only 1 value for a prime for the life span of the application? Primes are a good candidate to be cached.

Comment: A command line program that terminates after one query would be an obvious example. In any case, keeping global state is ugly and should always be considered a trade-off. And I would go so far as to say the sieve (generated at runtime) is essentially useless. If your prime candidates are small enough that you can fit a sieve that size in memory, you should just have a `static const` bitmap of which numbers are prime and use that, rather than filling it at runtime.

Comment: Or, as a general rule, memoization is almost always useless unless you can somehow omit large spans, since whenever you can afford that much memory, you could even more easily afford that much disk space/`.text` segment size.

Comment: Sieve of Eratosthenes is a good (well, good-ish) way of solving the problem "generate all of the primes up to *n*". It's a wasteful way of solving the problem "is *n* prime?"

Comment: The Sieve of Eratosthenes is only "Embarrassingly Parallel" for MIMD not for SIMD. A modern computer uses several technologies for parallelization and MIMD is only one of them. If you find a way to make it parallel for SIMD please let me know!

Answer (score 18):

Stephen Canon answered it very well!

But

- The algorithm can be improved further by observing that all primes are of the form 6k ± 1, with the exception of 2 and 3.
- This is because all integers can be expressed as (6k + i) for some integer k and for i = −1, 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4; 2 divides (6k + 0), (6k + 2), (6k + 4); and 3 divides (6k + 3).
- So a more efficient method is to test if n is divisible by 2 or 3, then to check through all the numbers of form 6k ± 1 ≤ √n.
- This is 3 times as fast as testing all m up to √n.

  ```
  int IsPrime(unsigned int number) {
      if (number <= 3 && number > 1) 
          return 1;            // as 2 and 3 are prime
      else if (number%2==0 || number%3==0) 
          return 0;     // check if number is divisible by 2 or 3
      else {
          unsigned int i;
          for (i=5; i*i<=number; i+=6) {
              if (number % i == 0 || number%(i + 2) == 0) 
                  return 0;
          }
          return 1; 
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: you should return `0` when (number == 1), as 1 isn't a prime number.

Comment: These kind of optimisations are IMO irrelevant for this task : why stop at the form _6k ± 1 except 2 and 3_, which revrites in _n^2 mod 6 = 1_, when you can have _n^4 mod 30 = 1 except 2,3,5_ ... in fact, you can go forever because you're using prime numbers to do this optimisation ... and this IS the very principle of the more general Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm :)

Comment: @GhilesZ: I disagree, this is very relevant to the problem and with a single "||" allows the basic loop to run effectively 3 times faster.

Comment: In addition for number==1 it is correctly returning 0 (non-prime) with the tested confition "(number%2==0)", si there's no bug at all

Comment: The Eratosthene methoid is a completely different method that requires allocating a large O(n) array of booleans and it will not necessarily be faster due to indexed accesses. This code is fine as it optimizes first the case of the two first primes 2 and 3 (that's why the loop steps by 2*3).

Comment: You could continue using the same technic using the next prime (5) by steps of (30 == 2*3*5) and tests 9 candidate values (30k+{1;7;11;13;17;19;21;23;29}), still without using an array for the crible
However I think it is faster to precompute sqrt(i) once instead of computing product i*i at each loop.

Comment: (edit: remove 30k+21 which is divisible by 3). You see that the first optimization on the two first primes gains a lot (6 times less loops testing 2 candidates, i.e. 3 times faster than loops on all odds). The optimization on the first 3 primes (30 times less loops testing 8 candidates, will be i.e. 30/8=3.75 times faster than loops on all odds), but the gain is less impressive. This is general: you won't be significantly faster with a generic crible!

Comment: Code fails when `n` is a large prime near `UINT_MAX` as `i*i` overflows.

Answer (score 10):

1. Build a table of small primes, and check if they divide your input number.
2. If the number survived to 1, try pseudo primality tests with increasing basis. See [Miller-Rabin primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test) for example.
3. If your number survived to 2, you can conclude it is prime if it is below some well known bounds. Otherwise your answer will only be "probably prime". You will find some values for these bounds in the wiki page.

Comment: +1: complete overkill for what the questioner was asking, but correct nonetheless.

Comment: Note that [Guy L.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1344896/guy-l) recently suggested using Miller-Rabin in an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31759873/15168) too, and linked to http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test#C — which shows an implementation in C using [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).  The entry also has a number of implementations in a wide variety of other languages too.

Answer (score 4):

this program is much efficient for checking a single number for primality check.

```
bool check(int n){
    if (n <= 3) {
        return n > 1;
    }

    if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
        int sq=sqrt(n); //include math.h or use i*i<n in for loop
    for (int i = 5; i<=sq; i += 6) {
        if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: To test a prime, you should go all the way from `i=2` to `i<=ceil(sqrt(n))`. You missed 2 numbers in your test: First, cast to `(int)` makes `sqrt(n)` trunk the decimals. Second, you used `i<sq`, when it should be `i<=sq`. Now, suppose a number that fits this problem. A composite number `n` that has `ceil(sqrt(n))` as the smaller factor. Your inner loop runs for i like: (5, 7), (11, 13), (17, 19), (23, 25), (29, 31), (35, 37), (41, 43), and so on, `n%i` and `n%(i+2)`. Suppose we get `sqrt(1763)=41.98`. Being `1763=41*43` a composite number. Your loop will run only until `(35, 37)` and fail.

Comment: @DrBeco nice observation! thanks for example. updated the code.

Comment: After analyzing carefully the `ceil()` problem, I realized that although lots of sites recommend it, its just overkill. You can trunk and test just `i<=sqrt(n)` and it will be ok. The test cases are large tween primes. Example: `86028221*86028223=7400854980481283` and `sqrt(7400854980481283)~86028222`. And the smaller know tween primes, `2` and `3`, gives `sqrt(6)=2.449` that trunked will still leave `2`. (But smaller is not a test case, just a comparison to make a point). So, yes, the algorithm is correct now. No need to use `ceil()`.

Comment: Commented alternate code `i*i<n` fails when `n` is a large prime as `i*i` overflows.

Answer (score 3):

After reading this question, I was intrigued by the fact that some answers offered optimization by running a loop with multiples of 2*3=6.

So I create a new function with the same idea, but with multiples of 2*3*5=30.

```
int check235(unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long sq, i;

    if(n<=3||n==5)
        return n>1;

    if(n%2==0 || n%3==0 || n%5==0)
        return 0;

    if(n<=30)
        return checkprime(n); /* use another simplified function */

    sq=ceil(sqrt(n));
    for(i=7; i<=sq; i+=30)
        if (n%i==0 || n%(i+4)==0 || n%(i+6)==0 || n%(i+10)==0 || n%(i+12)==0 
           || n%(i+16)==0 || n%(i+22)==0 || n%(i+24)==0)
            return 0;

        return 1;
}
```

By running both functions and checking times I could state that this function is really faster. Lets see 2 tests with 2 different primes:

```
$ time ./testprimebool.x 18446744069414584321 0
f(2,3)
Yes, its prime.    
real    0m14.090s
user    0m14.096s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time ./testprimebool.x 18446744069414584321 1
f(2,3,5)
Yes, its prime.    
real    0m9.961s
user    0m9.964s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time ./testprimebool.x 18446744065119617029 0
f(2,3)
Yes, its prime.    
real    0m13.990s
user    0m13.996s
sys     0m0.004s

$ time ./testprimebool.x 18446744065119617029 1
f(2,3,5)
Yes, its prime.    
real    0m10.077s
user    0m10.068s
sys     0m0.004s
```

So I thought, would someone gain too much if generalized? I came up with a function that will do a siege first to clean a given list of primordial primes, and then use this list to calculate the bigger one.

```
int checkn(unsigned long n, unsigned long *p, unsigned long t)
{
    unsigned long sq, i, j, qt=1, rt=0;
    unsigned long *q, *r;

    if(n<2)
        return 0;

    for(i=0; i<t; i++)
    {
        if(n%p[i]==0)
            return 0;
        qt*=p[i];
    }
    qt--;

    if(n<=qt)
        return checkprime(n); /* use another simplified function */

    if((q=calloc(qt, sizeof(unsigned long)))==NULL)
    {
        perror("q=calloc()");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0; i<t; i++)
        for(j=p[i]-2; j<qt; j+=p[i])
            q[j]=1;

    for(j=0; j<qt; j++)
        if(q[j])
            rt++;

    rt=qt-rt;
    if((r=malloc(sizeof(unsigned long)*rt))==NULL)
    {
        perror("r=malloc()");
        exit(1);
    }
    i=0;
    for(j=0; j<qt; j++)
        if(!q[j])
            r[i++]=j+1;

    free(q);

    sq=ceil(sqrt(n));
    for(i=1; i<=sq; i+=qt+1)
    {
        if(i!=1 && n%i==0)
            return 0;
        for(j=0; j<rt; j++)
            if(n%(i+r[j])==0)
                return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I assume I did not optimize the code, but it's fair. Now, the tests. Because so many dynamic memory, I expected the list 2 3 5 to be a little slower than the 2 3 5 hard-coded. But it was ok as you can see bellow. After that, time got smaller and smaller, culminating the best list to be:

> 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19

With 8.6 seconds. So if someone would create a hardcoded program that makes use of such technique I would suggest use the list 2 3 and 5, because the gain is not that big. But also, if willing to code, this list is ok. Problem is you cannot state all cases without a loop, or your code would be very big (There would be 1658879 `ORs`, that is `||` in the respective internal `if`). The next list:

> 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23

time started to get bigger, with 13 seconds. Here the whole test:

```
$ time ./testprimebool.x 18446744065119617029 2 3 5
f(2,3,5)
Yes, its prime.
real    0m12.668s
user    0m12.680s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time ./testprimebool.x 18446744065119617029 2 3 5 7
f(2,3,5,7)
Yes, its prime.
real    0m10.889s
user    0m10.900s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time ./testprimebool.x 18446744065119617029 2 3 5 7 11
f(2,3,5,7,11)
Yes, its prime.
real    0m10.021s
user    0m10.028s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time ./testprimebool.x 18446744065119617029 2 3 5 7 11 13
f(2,3,5,7,11,13)
Yes, its prime.
real    0m9.351s
user    0m9.356s
sys     0m0.004s

$ time ./testprimebool.x 18446744065119617029 2 3 5 7 11 13 17
f(2,3,5,7,11,13,17)
Yes, its prime.
real    0m8.802s
user    0m8.800s
sys     0m0.008s

$ time ./testprimebool.x 18446744065119617029 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19
f(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19)
Yes, its prime.
real    0m8.614s
user    0m8.564s
sys     0m0.052s

$ time ./testprimebool.x 18446744065119617029 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23
f(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23)
Yes, its prime.
real    0m13.013s
user    0m12.520s
sys     0m0.504s

$ time ./testprimebool.x 18446744065119617029 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29
f(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29)                                                                                                                         
q=calloc(): Cannot allocate memory
```

---

PS. I did not free(r) intentionally, giving this task to the OS, as the memory would be freed as soon as the program exited, to gain some time. But it would be wise to free it if you intend to keep running your code after the calculation.

---

**BONUS**

```
int check2357(unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long sq, i;

    if(n<=3||n==5||n==7)
        return n>1;

    if(n%2==0 || n%3==0 || n%5==0 || n%7==0)
        return 0;

    if(n<=210)
        return checkprime(n); /* use another simplified function */

    sq=ceil(sqrt(n));
    for(i=11; i<=sq; i+=210)
    {    
        if(n%i==0 || n%(i+2)==0 || n%(i+6)==0 || n%(i+8)==0 || n%(i+12)==0 || 
   n%(i+18)==0 || n%(i+20)==0 || n%(i+26)==0 || n%(i+30)==0 || n%(i+32)==0 || 
   n%(i+36)==0 || n%(i+42)==0 || n%(i+48)==0 || n%(i+50)==0 || n%(i+56)==0 || 
   n%(i+60)==0 || n%(i+62)==0 || n%(i+68)==0 || n%(i+72)==0 || n%(i+78)==0 || 
   n%(i+86)==0 || n%(i+90)==0 || n%(i+92)==0 || n%(i+96)==0 || n%(i+98)==0 || 
   n%(i+102)==0 || n%(i+110)==0 || n%(i+116)==0 || n%(i+120)==0 || n%(i+126)==0 || 
   n%(i+128)==0 || n%(i+132)==0 || n%(i+138)==0 || n%(i+140)==0 || n%(i+146)==0 || 
   n%(i+152)==0 || n%(i+156)==0 || n%(i+158)==0 || n%(i+162)==0 || n%(i+168)==0 || 
   n%(i+170)==0 || n%(i+176)==0 || n%(i+180)==0 || n%(i+182)==0 || n%(i+186)==0 || 
   n%(i+188)==0 || n%(i+198)==0)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Time:

```
$ time ./testprimebool.x 18446744065119617029 7
h(2,3,5,7)
Yes, its prime.
real    0m9.123s
user    0m9.132s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: Bonus: `101`-`199` primals all fail here because `101 % (11+90)`.

Comment: need to stop at `n%(i+86)` or check `n > i+k`

Comment: Well done, sir. I'll take a look. Thank you. The same problem happens with function `check235()` for primes 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 and 29

Comment: Solution: need to move these reminders to an array, iterate through and break iteration when `i+arr[k] >= n`

Comment: I thought about that, but I don't want a array, because of the `if` with constants can be better optimized by the compiler. I edited to add an exception and keep the current structure intact. But I agree, with an array can be better to human eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Check the modulus of each integer from 2 up to the root of the number you're checking.

If modulus equals zero then it's not prime.

pseudo code:

```
bool IsPrime(int target)
{
  for (i = 2; i <= root(target); i++)
  {
    if ((target mod i) == 0)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Of course, the downside is that the the sqrt is calculated on every iteration, which will slow it down a lot.

Comment: Any reasonable compiler should be able to detect that root(target) is a loop invariant and hoist it.

Comment: (and if you have a compiler that can't do that optimization, you should absolutely file a bug to let the compiler writer know that they're missing this optimization.)

Comment: along with many other potential (micro)optimistations, If you manually get the sqrt before the for statement you can check the mod of that as well (and return false if 0).

Comment: What if the target value is 1?

Answer (score 2):

I would just add that no even number (bar 2) can be a prime number. This results in another condition prior to for loop. So the end code should look like this:

```
int IsPrime(unsigned int number) {
    if (number <= 1) return 0; // zero and one are not prime
    if ((number > 2) && ((number % 2) == 0)) return 0; //no even number is prime number (bar 2)
    unsigned int i;
    for (i=2; i*i<=number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `i*i<=number` fails when `number` is a large prime as `i*i` overflows.

Answer (score 1):

```
int is_prime(int val)
{
   int div,square;

   if (val==2) return TRUE;    /* 2 is prime */
   if ((val&1)==0) return FALSE;    /* any other even number is not */

   div=3;
   square=9;    /* 3*3 */
   while (square<val)
   {
     if (val % div == 0) return FALSE;    /* evenly divisible */
     div+=2;
     square=div*div;
   }
   if (square==val) return FALSE;
   return TRUE;
}
```

Handling of 2 and even numbers are kept out of the main loop which only handles odd numbers divided by odd numbers. This is because an odd number modulo an even number will always give a non-zero answer which makes those tests redundant. Or, to put it another way, an odd number *may* be evenly divisible by another odd number but *never* by an even number (E*E=>E, E*O=>E, O*E=>E and O*O=>O).

A division/modulus is really costly on the x86 architecture although how costly varies (see http://gmplib.org/~tege/x86-timing.pdf). Multiplications on the other hand are quite cheap.

Comment: `square=div*div;` fails when `val` is a large prime.

Answer (score 1):

**Avoid overflow bug**

```
unsigned i, number;
...
for (i=2; i*i<=number; i++) {  // Buggy
for (i=2; i*i<=number; i += 2) {  // Buggy
// or
for (i=5; i*i<=number; i+=6) { // Buggy
```

These forms are incorrect when `number` is a prime and `i*i` is near the max value of the type.

Problem exists with all integer types, `signed, unsigned` and wider.

Example:

Let `UINT_MAX_SQRT` as the floor of the square root of the maximum integer value.  E.g. 65535 when `unsigned` is 32-bit.

With `for (i=2; i*i<=number; i++)`, this 10-year old failure occurs because when `UINT_MAX_SQRT*UINT_MAX_SQRT <= number` and `number` is a prime, the next iteration results in a multiplication overflow.  Had the type been a *signed* type, the overflow is UB.  With *unsigned types*, this itself is not UB, yet logic has broken down.  Interations continue until a *truncated* product exceeds `number`.  An incorrect result may occur.  With 32-bit `unsigned`, try 4,294,967,291‬ which is a prime.

If `some_integer_type_MAX` been a [Mersenne Prime](https://www.mersenne.org/primes/), `i*i<=number` is *never* true.

---

To avoid this bug, consider  that `number%i`, `number/i` is efficient on many compilers as the calculations of the quotient and remainder are done together, thus incurring no extra cost to do both vs. just 1.

A simple full-range solution:

```
bool IsPrime(unsigned number) {
  // Easy test for even numbers
  if (number % 2 == 0) {
    return number == 2;
  }

  for(unsigned i = 3; i <= number/i; i += 2){
    if(number % i == 0){
      return false;
    }
  }

  return number >= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if a number is prime i'm using a **Miller**/**Rabin** Algorithm.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef size_t positive_number; // also try __uint128_t

static inline positive_number multiplication_modulo(positive_number lhs, positive_number rhs, positive_number mod) {
    positive_number res = 0; // we avoid overflow in modular multiplication
    for (lhs %= mod, rhs %= mod; rhs; (rhs & 1) ? (res = (res + lhs) % mod) : 0, lhs = (lhs << 1) % mod, rhs >>= 1);
    return res; // <= (lhs * rhs) % mod
}

static int is_prime(positive_number n, int k) {
    positive_number a = 0, b, c, d, e, f, g; int h, i;
    if ((n == 1) == (n & 1)) return n == 2;
    if (n < 51529) // fast constexpr check for small primes (removable)
        return (n & 1) & ((n < 6) * 42 + 0x208A2882) >> n % 30 && (n < 49 || (n % 7 && n % 11 && n % 13 && n % 17 && n % 19 && n % 23 && n % 29 && n % 31 && n % 37 && (n < 1369 || (n % 41 && n % 43 && n % 47 && n % 53 && n % 59 && n % 61 && n % 67 && n % 71 && n % 73 && ( n < 6241 || (n % 79 && n % 83 && n % 89 && n % 97 && n % 101 && n % 103 && n % 107 && n % 109 && n % 113 && ( n < 16129 || (n % 127 && n % 131 && n % 137 && n % 139 && n % 149 && n % 151 && n % 157 && n % 163 && n % 167 && ( n < 29929 || (n % 173 && n % 179 && n % 181 && n % 191 && n % 193 && n % 197 && n % 199 && n % 211 && n % 223))))))))));
    for (b = c = n - 1, h = 0; !(b & 1); b >>= 1, ++h);
    for (; k--;) {
        for (g = 0; g < sizeof(positive_number); ((char*)&a)[g++] = rand()); // random number
        do for (d = e = 1 + a % c, f = n; (d %= f) && (f %= d););
        while (d > 1 && f > 1);
        for (d = f = 1; f <= b; f <<= 1);
        for (; f >>= 1; d = multiplication_modulo(d, d, n), f & b && (d = multiplication_modulo(e, d, n)));
        if (d == 1) continue;
        for (i = h; i-- && d != c; d = multiplication_modulo(d, d, n));
        if (d != c) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The test is to print the first primes :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    // C Fast Iterative Algorithm
    // The First 10,000 Primes
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 104730 ; ++i)
        if (is_prime(i, 20))
            printf("%d %c", i, (i+1) % 10 ? ' ' : '\n');

    if (is_prime(9223372036854775783UL, 12))
        if (is_prime(9223372036854775643UL, 12))
            if (!is_prime(3037000493ULL * 3037000453ULL, 12))
                printf("Done.\n");
}
```

You can put it into a `primes.c` file then compile + execute :

```sh
gcc -O3 -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic primes.c ; ./a.out ;
```

This variant of the Fermat test has a polynomial runtime in `log(n)`.
The **__uint128_t** type may be available with [128-bit integers GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html).

Answer (score 0):

Using Sieve of Eratosthenes, computation is quite faster compare to "known-wide" prime numbers algorithm.

By using pseudocode from it's wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), I be able to have the solution on C#.

```
public bool IsPrimeNumber(int val) {
    // Using Sieve of Eratosthenes.
    if (val < 2)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Reserve place for val + 1 and set with true.
    var mark = new bool[val + 1];
    for(var i = 2; i <= val; i++)
    {
        mark[i] = true;
    }

    // Iterate from 2 ... sqrt(val).
    for (var i = 2; i <= Math.Sqrt(val); i++)
    {
        if (mark[i])
        {
            // Cross out every i-th number in the places after i (all the multiples of i).
            for (var j = (i * i); j <= val; j += i)
            {
                mark[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return mark[val];
}
```

IsPrimeNumber(1000000000) takes 21s 758ms.

***NOTE***: Value might vary depend on hardware specifications.